# Zend_Auth / Zend_Session error and storing objects in Auth Storage

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-session

I have been having a bit of a problem with Zend_Auth and keep getting an error within my Acl.

Within my Login Controller I setup my Zend_Auth storage as follows

```
$auth   = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

if ($result->isValid()) {
    $userId = $adapter->getResultRowObject(array('user_id'), null)->user_id;

    $user   = new User_Model_User;
    $users  = new User_Model_UserMapper;

    $users->find($userId, $user);

    $auth->getStorage()->write(
        $user
    );
}
```

This seems to work well and I am able to use the object stored in the Zend_Auth storage within View Helpers without any problems. The problem that I seem to be having is when I try to use this within my Acl, below is a snippet from my Acl, as soon as it gets to the `if($auth->hasIdentity()) {` line I get the exception detailed further down.

The `$user->getUserLevel()` is a methord within the User Model that allows me to convert the user_level_id that is stored in the database to a meaning full name. I am assuming that the auto loader sees these kind of methords and tries to load all the classes that would be required.

When looking at the exception it appears to be struggling to find the class as it is stored in a module, I have the Auto Loader Name Space setup in my application.ini.

Could anyone help with resolving this?

```
class App_Controller_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    protected $_roleName;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if($auth->hasIdentity()) {     
            $user = $auth->getIdentity();   
            $this->_roleName = strtolower($user->getUserLevel());        
        } else {
            $this->_roleName = 'guest';
        }
    }
}


Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() -
\Web\library\Zend\Loader.php(Line:146): Error #2 include_once() [&lt;a href='function.include'&gt;function.include&lt;/a&gt;]:
Failed opening 'Menu\Model\UserLevel.php' for inclusion
(include_path='\Web\application/../library;\Web\library;.;C:\php5\pear') Array' in \Web\library\Zend\Session.php:493

Stack trace:
#0 \Web\library\Zend\Session\Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true)
#1 \Web\library\Zend\Auth\Storage\Session.php(87): Zend_Session_Namespace-&gt;__construct('Zend_Auth')
#2 \Web\library\Zend\Auth.php(91): Zend_Auth_Storage_Session-&gt;__construct()
#3 \Web\library\Zend\A in \Web\library\Zend\Session.php on line 493
```

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Have you bootstrapped your module?

Comment: Hi Ashley, how do you mean bootstrapped, in my config I have the following lines, do I need anything else... Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Menu_", resources.modules[] = ""

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to un-serializing an object. The exception is telling you what's wrong. Zend_Loader cannot find your `UserLevel` class (I'm assuming this is a member of `User_Model_User`).

Is your include path set correctly at the time when your ACL is constructed?

A hacky work-around would be to add

```
require_once 'path/to/Menu/Model/UserLevel.php';
```

to your ACL class file.

Comment: Hi Phil, I have added the module directory to the include path with no luck. Including each file would work but unfortunately I’d end up including almost all my models as they all cascade from each other. I may go back to my old way and store the user id instead of the user model and load the model when needed. Thanks for your help.